# can't get strip_tags() to work

Tags: php, strip-tags

trying to use this function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

against this:

```
[link-code-html] => <a href="http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-3782261-10563989">invisibleSHIELD for the iPhone 3G</a><img src="http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-3782261-10563989" width="1" height="1" border="0"/>
```

while

```
echo(strip_tags($each->{'link-code-html'}),'<a>'));
```

returns me:

invisibleSHIELD for the iPhone 3G

it doesn't seems like I have img (1x1) next to it, but it's missing  link

any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand if you get the string without a and img tags or just on of them.

Comment: This is the output from your code: `<a href="http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-3782261-10563989">invisibleSHIELD for the iPhone 3G</a>`...the link seems to be there

Comment: sorry I dont get a or img, just plain text string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<a>` is not within the call of `strip_tags()`, it should be:

```
echo(strip_tags($each->{'link-code-html'}, '<a>'));
                                                ^
```